# How does $parent property work in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Why does scope.$parent work to populate a property on the parent in some cases but not others?

I have the following 2 directives specified in a view:

```
<directive1
    model="model1"
    ng-repeat="bar in bars"
    formCtrl="$parent.forms[bar.id]"></directive1>

<directive2
    model="model2"
    formCtrl="forms.foo"></directive2>
```

In the first directive, if I dont use $parent.forms, the forms property wont populate with those forms generated from the bars collection. In the second directive, if I use $parent.forms, the forms property wont populate with the foo form.

I'm binding scope in my directives like so:

```
scope:
    model: '='
    form: '='
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any detail to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-repeat property in directive1 is creating an isolated scope. This means it doesn't recognise forms[bar.id], as the forms property isn't part of the scope created by the ng-repeat. $parent is therefore looking to the parent scope to find the forms property.

However, although $parent does solve the problem, it is considered 'bad practice' in Angular by many. The commonly spouted phrase is 'if you don't have a dot, you're doing it wrong'. Instead of using $parent, you should instead create a child of forms (eg. foo, as you've done in directive2), and then use forms.foo[bar.id] in your formCtrl declaration.

What we're left with then is:

```
<directive1 
    model="model1"
    ng-repeat="bar in bars"
    formCtrl="forms.foo[bar.id]">
</directive1>
```

For more information, read up on prototypal inheritance at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: What if I wanted to have a particular structure in the parent scope?
- forms
  - id1: [foo:Form, bar: Form]
  - id2: [foo:Form, bar: Form]
and not
- forms
  - foo: [id1: Form, id2: Form]
  - bar: [id1: Form, id2: Form]

It seems I'd have to use $parent in that situation

Comment: 1. Why does the dot causes the isolate scope to look in the parent?
2. When I use $parent, I don't have to instantiate the forms object on the parent. Just specifying it in the directive creates it in the parent scope at runtime. Why is that?

Comment: The $parent prevents the isolated scope of the ng-repeat creating a property with the same name (eg. forms) by telling it to use the already existing object the parent scope.
Using the dot already indicates the name of the parent on the parent scope, therefore the $parent isn't necessary.

Comment: "Using the dot already indicates the name of the parent on the parent scope"

Is there documentation anywhere that describes this in more detail? I'm really confused about this still.